# Ethers.js recovers wrong address when signing its transactions with elliptic.js

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, nodejs, signature, ecdsa

Can someone show me how to correctly sign an ether's unsigned transaction hash using `elliptic` npm package. Below is my attempt (with some random private key) and transaction should ideally fail with "only minter". Any help is appreciated, getting pretty desperate.

```typescript
import * as elliptic from "elliptic"
import { ethers, Contract, JsonRpcProvider, Transaction, Signature } from 'ethers';


const chainId = 13

const ec = new elliptic.ec("secp256k1")

const privateKey = "c395c9afc567105569ccdc2a858d4659bb66eb6ba1530c2d0c3e88c071c15cba"
const publicKey = ec.keyFromPrivate(privateKey).getPublic(false, "hex").slice(2)
const address = `0x` + ethers.keccak256(`0x`+publicKey).slice(-40)
const checksumedAddress = ethers.getAddress(address)

const abi = [{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "_target",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "mintAmount",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}]

async function main() {
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("https://coston-api.flare.network/ext/C/rpc")
  const contract = new Contract('0xC06496FA0551bf4996fb5Df876cBcC6F1d836460', abi, provider)
  const action = 'mintAmount'
  const params = ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 10]
  const method = contract.getFunction(action)
  const baseTx = await method.populateTransaction(...params)
  const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(checksumedAddress)

  const unsignedTx = {
    ...baseTx,
    nonce: nonce,
    chainId: chainId,
    gasLimit: ethers.toBeHex("10000000"),
    gasPrice: ethers.toBeHex("10000000"),
  }

  // external transaction signature
  const tx = Transaction.from(unsignedTx)
  const _signature = ec.sign(
    tx.unsignedHash,
    Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'),
    { canonical: true }
  )
  const signature = Signature.from({
    r: _signature.r.toString(),
    s: _signature.s.toString(),
    yParity: _signature.recoveryParam as 0 | 1
  })
  const x = ethers.recoverAddress(tx.unsignedHash, signature)
  if (x !== checksumedAddress) throw new Error("invalid signature")

  // sign transaction
  tx.signature
  const signedTx = Transaction.from({
    ...unsignedTx,
    from: checksumedAddress,
    signature: signature
  })

  // send transaction to node
  await provider.send('eth_sendRawTransaction', [signedTx.serialized])
}

main()
```

but I can't get the recovered address to match (I know `address` is derived correctly from the signing private key). I also tried replacing `tx.unsignedHash` with `const actualUnsignedHash = ethers.hashMessage(tx.unsignedHash)` in case transaction expects a signed message but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that `ec.sign` expected the unsigned hash to be a `BN` type. Because the type of inputs with prefixed `0x` is just too vague.